# How to use SQL file on android application

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am developing an application and I am having some trouble adding a database that I already have on my computer to the phone, so I can use it in the phone.
I have an SQL file (sample shown below), and I have an application. How can I insert this SQL table in my apk so I can access data from my application? 
Also is this the wrong format of file?

thank you

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "mytable22";
CREATE TABLE "mytable22" (
    "word" varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    "pos" numeric(5,3),
    "neg" numeric(5,3),
    "neut" numeric(5,3)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "mytable22" OWNER TO "ranaakel";

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of "mytable22"
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "mytable22" VALUES ('اضاء', '0.000', '0.000', '1.000');
INSERT INTO "mytable22" VALUES ('ضيف', '0.000', '0.000', '1.000');
INSERT INTO "mytable22" VALUES ('ضيف', '0.000', '0.000', '1.000');
INSERT INTO "mytable22" VALUES ('ضعف', '0.125', '0.000', '0.875');
INSERT INTO "mytable22" VALUES ('ضعف', '0.500', '0.250', '0.250');
INSERT INTO "mytable22" VALUES ('ضرر', '0.000', '0.125', '0.875');
```

Comment: Those are just querys. Do you actually already have a db? If not you can just execute the querys to create a db on your device. If you already have a db - which by the way has to be a SQLite db - you can put that in your apps ressources.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller Hello, I created a database using Navicat lite, and when I dump the database i get this in the a .sql extension. How can we create a SQLite db? what specific software do we need? after that do you have any specific tutorial I can follow to use the db after inserting it in the apps resources? thank you